# IP lookup tables and data structure?

Tags: data-structures, ip

One technique to reduce the size of IP lookup tables is to remove redundancy. When a prefix P is
longer than a prefix P’ (i.e. their first P’ bits are the same) and they both have the same next hop, which
prefix can be removed from the table? How would you implement such compression process assuming
the original table was implemented in a Trie

Comment: A few concrete examples would help others to understand exactly what you're asking, which will help you get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is called summary routing. When an IP is located within another route entry and uses the same gateway you can simply forget that IP or network entry.

Depending on how exactly your data tree is organized, you might have to check each entry against all others. With an appropriately sorted tree you'd only have to check one branch. Or when it's really cleverly sorted you just check the next lower entry.